# After I created a nest in D3, how do I reset the scale to new values?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg

Question in last code block, here's the set up...

I'm importing a somewhat large json file and converting it to a nest like so...

```
var dataURL = "season.json";
d3.json(dataURL, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(data) {
       return data.season;
    })
    .entries(data);
```

Which makes a nest sample like so...

```
[{
"key": "2000",
"values": [{
    "season": 2000,
    "started": 54,
    "points": 8.4,
    "name": "joe"
}, {
    "season": 2000,
    "started": 1,
    "points": 5.7,
    "name": "jane"
}]
}, {
"key": "2001",
"values": [{
    "season": 2001,
    "started": 24,
    "points": 9.5,
    "name": "jill"
}, {
    "season": 2001,
    "started": 29,
    "points": 5.3,
    "name": "john"
}]
```

I'm making an individual svg for each season and will populate it with circles. This works fine...

```
d3.select("#chart").selectAll("svg")
   .data(nest) // use nest for data
   .enter().append("svg") // for each datapoint, append an svg
   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .attr('class', 'chart')
   .each(function(d, i) { // for each svg...
       rscale = d3.scale.linear()
                   .domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.points; }), 
                d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.points; }) ])
                   .range([3,50]);
       d3.select(this).selectAll('circle')
          .data(d.values)
          .enter()
          .append("circle")
            .attr("class", function(d) {
                return d.name;
            })
            .attr("cy", 65)
            .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
                return i * 28 + 20;
            })
            .attr("r", function(d, i) {
                if (d.points >= 2) {
                   return rscale(d.points);
                } else {
                   return 2;
             }
    })
```

Working great up to this point but now I want to change circle radius to reflect games started. I was able to get this far...

```
$("button").click(function() {
     var selectedMetric = $(this).attr("id"); //returns either "started" or "points"
     d3.selectAll("circle")
         .transition()
         .duration(1000)
         .attr('r', function(d) {


              // I used rscale above successfully.
              // How do I set a new scale to reflect 
              // "started" values found in the nest??

              return d[selectedMetric]


         });
     });
});
```

Comment: Can you tell us what `d`looks like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a scale 'map' for each property of your data set you might want to use in your circle scaling. (d3.extent does the job of d3.min and d3.max in the same go). Then you can call the scale you want by the name of the data property.

```
.each(function(d, i) { // for each svg...

  var scaleThese = ["started", "points"];
    var scales = {};
    scaleThese.forEach (function (prop) {
        scales[prop] = d3.scale.linear()
                       .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[prop]; }))
                       .range([3,50]);
    });

// ... then later on ...        

    .attr('r', function(d) {
              // where selectedMetric is 'points' or 'started'
              return scales[selectedMetric](d[selectedMetric]);
     });
```

Note that these scales (as is the existing rscale) are local to each svg (each nested portion of data)

Comment: For posterity... In my case, the `var scaleThese = ["started", "points"];` and `var scales = {};` bits had to be declared outside of the .each statement so they could be used by buttons and selectors throughout the page.